# mail is not sent by device rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

[image]I am using device but confirmation and forget password mail is not sent. I have apply this code

```
devise.rb
config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'

developement.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address     ![enter image description here][2]         => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
      :port                 => 458,
      :domain               => 'gmail.com',
      :user_name            => 'xyz@gmail.com',
      :password             => '123456',
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

Smtp is working find in others project. Please suggest me where i am wrong

Comment: Please add `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` to development.rb and post the error

Comment: Are you over your gmail daily send limit?

Comment: @RajarshiDas Das after this i got this error = SocketError in Devise::PasswordsController#create, getaddrinfo: Name or service not known,

Comment: can you please post whole log error in your post ?

Comment: I have upload image @RajarshiDas and i have changed port number also localhost:9000

Comment: Actually I say log post you get from the server log development log. Please restart the server and chnage defualt_url it should be `localhost:9000` and port ``587`

Answer (score 0):

please update port :458 to :port => 587

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'gmail.com',
      :user_name            => 'xyz@gmail.com',
      :password             => '123456',
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```